# Herkunft von Muße bzw. Müßiggang

Tags: etymology

Woher stammt das Wort *Muße* und was hat es mit dem Verb *müssen* zu tun?

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mu%C3%9Fe https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%BCssen Sieht nach gleichem/sehr aehnlichem Wortursprung im Althochdeutschen aus.

Comment: Ähnliche Frage: Woher kommt das Wort *Dose*, und was hat es mit *dösen* zu tun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im [Deutschen Wörterbuch der Gebrüder Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GM08714#XGM08714) findet sich als Bedeutung 3a):

> Gelegenheit, freie Zeit etwas zu tun

Unter der Bedeutung 1) findet sich die Herkunft vom althochdeutschen *muoza* und im weiteren

> "ist das Substantiv zu müssen".

Somit haben beide Wörter offensichtlich den gleichen Wortstamm.

In dem Artikel zu "[müssen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=muessen)" findet sich dann die Erklärung, dass das Verb erst in späterer Zeit die heutige Bedeutung bekommen hat. Die Entwicklung ging dabei wohl über "Raum finden, Erlaubnis haben" ([Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%BCssen)) zum "gezwungenen sein".